# Unable to set locateStrategy to 'link text' for nightwatch.js page object

Tags: javascript, selenium, nightwatch.js, pageobjects

When setting a page object to use the locateStrategy of 'link text' like so:

```
checkboxesLink: {
    selector: 'Checkboxes',
    locateStrategy: 'link text',
}
```

nightwatch.js continues to try and use 'css selector' as the locateStrategy option. If I switch it to use 'xpath' it picks that up fine.

Error:

> ERROR: Unable to locate element: "Checkboxes" using: css selector

What/Where could the issue be?

**EDIT to show other attempts:**

```
checkboxesLink: {
    selector: 'Checkboxes',
    locateStrategy: 'linktext',
}
checkboxesLink: {
    selector: 'Checkboxes',
    locateStrategy: 'linkText',
}
checkboxesLink: {
    selector: 'Checkboxes',
    locateStrategy: 'link-text',
}
```

Comment: Add some more details like HTML etc

Comment: Only a guess since I don't use javascript, but perhaps it's "linktext" ?

Comment: @Prany HTML can be found at https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/

Comment: @BillHileman thanks but have tried that. I'll edit to show the different combos of 'link text' I have tried.

Comment: perhaps linktext could be simulated with xpath, like `"\\a[contains(text(), 'Checkboxes')]"`

Comment: @BillHileman I'm currently doing that as a workaround but am curious why it isn't working as expected. Thanks though. :)

Comment: Are you using Firefox?  Could be this old bug: https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/5772